# Installing SDL2 Development version on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sdl, sdl-2, apt

I am trying to install SDL2 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04. However there are 2 types of packages available on the repository, the 'normal' library version and the development files version.

```
libsdl2-2.0-0/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.4 amd64
  Simple DirectMedia Layer

libsdl2-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.4 amd64
  Simple DirectMedia Layer development files
```

What I am asking is are there differences between the two version for developing application/game using SDL2 and which one should I install if I am just starting to learn SDL2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu (and other Linux distributions) often divide up packages this way: the first package contains libraries and executables needed to run something compiled with the package (SDL2 in this case), the `dev` packages contains the headers, additional libraries or config files needed to compile a program with package. You want to install both; normally installing the `dev` version of the package will pull in the other as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You will need both, most likely :)

The lib package contains the binary SDL library. That's needed to run a program.

But in order to develop an application, you need the C header files to include in your source code - assuming that you want to create a program in C or C++. The compiler needs these files to 'see' the functions provided by the lib.

If you want to use SDL library in a different way, you could also use python and python-pygame-sdl2.